# problem with grub-efi

Tags: mac, grub-efi

I am installing ubuntu on my MacBook, following the instructions here:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html

Everything has gone well so far. But I have now come to number 19. The cd with GRUB2 is in the drive, but when I type 'sudo apt-get install grub-efi' it says:

package grub-efi is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
grub2-common grub-common

The Grub iso I downloaded and burned was this one:

http://forja.cenatic.es/frs/download.php/1381/super_grub_disk_hybrid-1.98s1.iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of the site states;

> I wrote this page when Ubuntu 10.10 was current. Since then, Ubuntu
>   11.04 has been released with improved support for installing directly to EFI-based computers.

This has also changed considerably since 11.04 and newer hardware has been released. I recommend you have a good read through the documentation found on this [MactelSupport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) documentation page.

Follow the steps outlined there and report back with any issues.

Comment: Following the instructions there and installing 11.10, but at the time where he writes: On the last dialog of the installer, be sure to click the “Advanced” button and choose to install the boot loader (grub) to your root Ubuntu partition, for example /dev/sda3. This will be the only partition with the EXT4 file system. I have a problem as that button does not exist. After the partitioning, it goes to 'Install Now' and starts installing.

Comment: I guess it fixed itself. Now the computer boots into rEFIx and selecting the Linux Penguin takes me to Grub boot, so all is good :)